# Can you play video fragements using oggz-chop?

Tags: video, html, video-streaming

I see that you can play ogg audio files, but I was wondering if you can play video ogz files using it using Apache?

http://www.xiph.org/oggz/

Comment: Hmm I think it can...http://github.com/kfish/liboggz/blob/master/apache/oggz-chop.conf.in

Comment: Yes, you can.  I've just confirmed that it indeed works on apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can: http://github.com/kfish/liboggz/blob/master/apache/oggz-chop.conf.in